# Create a blur shadow to a circular image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image, image-effects

I want a help to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEsoI.jpg) blur effect as a shadow on an image in flutter and make it circular like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a blur with `ImageFilter.blur` and then give it a slight color for it to blur with.

```
...
  child: Container(
    width:100,height:100,
    decoration:const BoxDecoration(
       image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(
              '...'),  // insert image path here
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
       shape:BoxShape.circle),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100/2), //divide width of Container by 2 to make it rounded
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter:ImageFilter.blur(
          sigmaX: 30, // mess with this to update blur
          sigmaY: 30
        ),
        child:Container(
          decoration:const BoxDecoration(
            shape:BoxShape.circle,
            color:Colors.black26  //change this color according to need.
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. this is worked fine but the problem that when i tried to add this with other widget the BackdropFilter covered all the screen. is there any way to control the size of the BackdropFilter and keep the blur looks good as it is ?

Comment: @AnasEzzat, just wrap the `BackdropFilter` with `ClipRRect` and give it a borderRadius. Check the updated answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

To implement blur effect you can use `BackdropFilter` widget, to create a round image or widget one approach is to use `ClipRRect` widget:

```
BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: 10.0,
            sigmaY: 10.0,
          ),
          child: ClipRRect(
            child:Image.asset(path),

          ),
        ),
```