# Full blurring of the container instead of a circle

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have only one blurred circle but this is not possible and the outer parts of the circle i.e. Container are completely blurred. The same is true for CustomPoint.
[image: This Image]

Codes :

```
Center(
    child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
      Image.network(
          "https://mojekooh.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/1024px-Matterhorn_from_Domh%C3%BCtte_-_2.jpg"),
      ClipRRect(
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromARGB(33, 255, 0, 0),
                shape: BoxShape.circle),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]),
  ),
```

I searched the internet and did not find anything

**Update**:

My friends, I solved this problem:

```
    Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
        Image.network(
            "https://mojekooh.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/1024px-Matterhorn_from_Domh%C3%BCtte_-_2.jpg"),
        ClipOval(
         clipper: CoustomCircle(),
          child: BackdropFilter(
           filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(57, 255, 0, 0),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]),


class CoustomCircle extends CustomClipper<Rect> {

  @override
  Rect getClip(size){
    return const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 200, 200);
  }

@override
  bool shouldReclip(oldClipper){
  return true;
}
}
```

Comment: can you include the image that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friends, I solved this problem:

```
Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
        Image.network(
            "https://mojekooh.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/1024px-Matterhorn_from_Domh%C3%BCtte_-_2.jpg"),
        ClipOval(
         clipper: CoustomCircle(),
          child: BackdropFilter(
           filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(57, 255, 0, 0),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]),


class CoustomCircle extends CustomClipper<Rect> {

  @override
  Rect getClip(size){
    return const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 200, 200);
  }

@override
  bool shouldReclip(oldClipper){
  return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ImageFiltered widget instead of BackdropFilter

```
   Center(
        child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
          Image.network(
              "https://mojekooh.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/1024px-Matterhorn_from_Domh%C3%BCtte_-_2.jpg"),
          ClipRRect(
            child: ImageFiltered(
              imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 100,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(33, 255, 0, 0),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
```

Remember to import 'dart:ui'

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Rather than blurring out a container, you could blur out a `CircleAvatar`. Refer this too [Create a blur shadow to a circular image in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69422329/create-a-blur-shadow-to-a-circular-image-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks, I tested it, but my problem is still not solved